# Java strange "printf error: int int cannot be object"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, printf, syntax-error

I have this simple Java code:

```
package cal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1,
            n2,
            sum;

        System.out.print("enter first: ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("enter second: ");
        n2 = input.nextInt();

        sum = n1 + n2;
        System.out.printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

The error is at `printf`, it requires '(string, object[])', my 'sum' is `int` but can it be considered as an object?

Actually, first this code ran well, but after I made some change in the path to workplace, the code started to have this error.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @user3552387 I don't think so. Recheck please.

Comment: it's version 8 update 5, i'm sure

Comment: "Change in the path." Source compliance at 1.4.

Comment: @chrylis: i've changed it to 1.7 and it works again

Comment: I tried to run in jdk 7 with `project language level` starting from `1.4` to `1.7` and in 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 I got the following error:

**Error:(17, 18) java: binary literals are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable binary literals)


Error:(17, 18) java: binary literals are not supported in -source 1.4

  (use -source 7 or higher to enable binary literals)**

It Run only in **1.7**